# Box file download requires file_id?

Tags: box-api

(I'm pretty new to web development, so excuse any blatant ignorance)

I was wondering why Box's API requires file_id for [downloading a file](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-download-a-file)?

In their [Getting started](http://developers.box.com/get-started/) guide, we see them upload a file first, obtain the file_id of the uploaded file, and use that in the GET request to download a file.

But, why isn't there a way to download a file by name? i.e. by path from the toplevel box directory?

For context, I was just playing around with the box API and trying to see if I could download a file from my remote box directory to some local directory.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading a file by name works just fine if your primary world is a single user set of files.  But in Box, you usually end up having a few people, or a few dozen, or a few hundred people that all have access to the directory structure and the files.

The problem with downloading by name is that John, over in Program Management decides over the weekend that this project has grown, or you're done with the requirements gathering phase, and to keep the documents all organized is going to create a new sub-folder and move stuff in there.  Oh, and he'll rename the project folder, because the team decided on a new code-name.

If you tried to download files by path, or filename, that file would suddenly not be where you know where to get it, and you'd be pretty confused.  Or at least any software you'd written that wanted to check on that file would be.  When files (and folders) all have fixed IDs that don't change, it doesn't matter that John did a massive re-org.  If you'd created a wiki page with a link to that document, or you'd written some program that pulled content in off a spreadsheet stored in one of John's folders, your program would still work.  The file ID stays the same, even if someone else moves, renames, or uploads a new version of the file.

Comment: The Box API should also be able to handle a path to a folder or file for upload/download as well.  We have a set of folders for each business unit that are locked down.  We also have 3 different environments (Dev, Test and Prod).  Without a path based API call, I've got to store Box folder ids in my database.  If I pull the Prod db back to test, guess what?  All the ids are wrong.  Whereas if the API handled paths, I could put the root path in the web.config and store NOTHING in the db OR I can beat the heck out of Box servers walking down the folder structure from a root id.

Comment: There must be some system-wide setting to set filenames to unique, because my application sends and retrieves files to a Box endpoint by file name only. And if i attempt to PUT a file name which already exists, Box responds with an error.